# JQuery newly added to web app, getting not defined & 302 Moved Temporarily

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, freemarker

I'm trying to add Jquery to a web app that uses freemarker for rendering & already has a few js libraries. I've tested the script in a static html page outside the web app & it works fine.

Firebug provides 3 clues (the whole thing is driving me crazy, clearly I'm missing some vital piece of info)
I'm using
`var $j = jQuery.noConflict();`
since there is dojo & Ext already

I get 2 syntax errors firebug is basically saying

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
location: http://localhost:8080/datatrans/js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js (line 1)
```

It actually shows this error twice in the console, because the `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC ...` exists twise in the generated file.

I did however include both in in my static mockup test & it didn't cause issues. Then it JQuery not defined & I've googled that & tried all the standard stuff order of loading etc.

Then lastly Firebug > Net > JS shows both
jquery-1.7.2.min.js
jquery-ui-1.8.20.custom.min.js
have a status of 302 Moved Temporarily

Quite the puzzle any ideas (I'm about to throw in the towel on this - haven't done that in years)

Comment: Why don't you include the script tags so we can see where you're trying to pull jQuery from? My guess is you're using relative paths perhaps. Also, the errors about the Doctype are because you have included them twice. Just include it once in the beginning of the generated HTML.

Comment: try to define the location as local instead of the http URL , e.g. <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>

Comment: Please post some html, so we can take a look and you can keep your head in place.